# query Database periodically and return Redirect c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sms-gateway

I have to develop an application that communicates with a sms center. Previously this was done through Sockets. But we are going to upgrade it to use http.
First the sms center would send request to a url which has a String parameter. I will have to store the string into a oracle db. That part is ok. The problem is that the application reads the db periodically and fetches records from the db and creates http GET to a url. The records which are strings would be sent as parameters.

ex: - http://ussdapp.provider.com/Main?Param1=val1

How do I create this response without the request? I am using c# MVC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would put this code somewhere outside the IIS server. The web server is designed to answer web requests, not to execute periodic tasks.

I implemented the similar task by creating a Windows service. You can also look at Windows Task Scheduler: you can schedule a program to be run at specific intervals.

Comment: can i use the Windows service to recieve the request too.

Comment: Yes. For example, you can host a WCF service on your Windows service and expose an HTTP endpoint.

Comment: What if i use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse in a different thread.

Comment: You mean on your IIS-hosted application? You can do this, granted, but how will you schedule this, to be done periodically?